# Titanium Studio

Tags: javascript, json, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have set up my table and rows to pull JSON data from my online database, but the problem is that I have paginated data. While my data shows up for the first page, I am unsure of how to set up my JSON pull so it will pull the JSON data from other paginated pages, especially if more pages are dynamically created. i.e. page=4, page=5. Example:

Data being pulled currently -

First page - http://testsite.com/data.json

Paginated page (1) - http://testsite.com/data.json?page=2

Paginated page (2) - http://testsite.com/data.json?page=3

etc.
Here is how my code is currently set up:

```
    var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;



var data = [],


    Detail = require('detail');

var barList = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    height: 366,
    width: 320,
    top: 0,
    left: 0
});
win.add(barList);
barList.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    Ti.API.info('data: ' + JSON.stringify(e.rowData.data));
    var detail = new Detail(e.rowData.data);
    detail.open({modal:true});
});

var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
xhr.onload = function () {
    var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
    Ti.API.info(json.length);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            className: 'bar-row',
            data: json[i].bar, 
            hasChild: true,
            filter: json[i].bar.name
        });
        var titleLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            text: json[i].bar.name,
            font: {
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            left: 70,
            top: 5,
            height: 20,
            width: 210
        });
        row.add(titleLabel);

        data.push(row);
    }
    barList.setData(data);
};
xhr.open('GET', 'http://testsite.com/data.json');
xhr.send();

win.open();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow,
    data = [],
    Detail = require('detail');

var barList = Titanium.UI.createTableView({
    height: 366,
    width: 320,
    top: 0,
    left: 0
});
win.add(barList);

barList.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    Ti.API.info('data: ' + JSON.stringify(e.rowData.data));
    var detail = new Detail(e.rowData.data);
    detail.open({modal:true});
});

function fetchTableData(page) {
    if(!page) return alert('Please add a page number!');
    page = page > 1 ? "?page=" + page : "";
    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
    xhr.onsuccess = function() {
        if(this.responseText) {
            appendTableData(this.responseText);
        }
    }
    xhr.open('GET', 'http://testsite.com/data.json' + page);
    xhr.send();
}

function appendTableData(response) {
    var json = JSON.parse(response);
    for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
        var row = Titanium.UI.createTableViewRow({
            className: 'bar-row',
            data: json[i].bar, 
            hasChild: true,
            filter: json[i].bar.name
        });
        var titleLabel = Titanium.UI.createLabel({
            text: json[i].bar.name,
            font: {
                fontSize: 14,
                fontWeight: 'bold'
            },
            left: 70,
            top: 5,
            height: 20,
            width: 210
        });
        row.add(titleLabel);
        barList.appendRow(row);            
    }
}

win.open();
fetchTableData(1);
```

Please note that it might be necessary to do more validity checks of the response...